# How are parent and children pages structured in middleman?

Tags: middleman

Using middleman, how is the directory stucture under the "source" directory intended to be if I want to have parent and child pages?

Any directions to examples are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Source folder structure

```
source/
  index.html.md
  foo.html.erb
  foo/
    bar.html.haml
```

### Resulting URLs

Provided that you have `directory_indexes` activated (more info here: [Pretty URLs](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/pretty-urls/)).

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/foo/
http://example.com/foo/bar/
```